# Understanding Glib polling system for file descriptors

Tags: c, asynchronous, glib, polling

I'm trying to understand glib polling system. As I understand, polling is a technique to watch file descriptors for events. The function `os_host_main_loop_wait` runs in a loop. You can see that it calls `glib_pollfds_fill`, `qemu_poll_ns` and `glib_pollfds_poll`. I'm trying to understand what this loop does by calling each of these functions.

```
static GArray *gpollfds;

static void glib_pollfds_fill(int64_t *cur_timeout)
{
    GMainContext *context = g_main_context_default();
    int timeout = 0;
    int64_t timeout_ns;
    int n;

    g_main_context_prepare(context, &max_priority);

    glib_pollfds_idx = gpollfds->len;
    n = glib_n_poll_fds;
    do {
        GPollFD *pfds;
        glib_n_poll_fds = n;
        g_array_set_size(gpollfds, glib_pollfds_idx + glib_n_poll_fds);
        //Gets current index's address on gpollfds array
        pfds = &g_array_index(gpollfds, GPollFD, glib_pollfds_idx);
        //Fills gpollfds's each element (pfds) with the file descriptor to be polled
        n = g_main_context_query(context, max_priority, &timeout, pfds,
                                 glib_n_poll_fds);
        //g_main_context_query returns the number of records actually stored in fds , or, 
        //if more than n_fds records need to be stored, the number of records that need to be stored.
    } while (n != glib_n_poll_fds);

    if (timeout < 0) {
        timeout_ns = -1;
    } else {
        timeout_ns = (int64_t)timeout * (int64_t)SCALE_MS;
    }

    *cur_timeout = qemu_soonest_timeout(timeout_ns, *cur_timeout);
}
static void glib_pollfds_poll(void)
{
    GMainContext *context = g_main_context_default();
    GPollFD *pfds = &g_array_index(gpollfds, GPollFD, glib_pollfds_idx);

    if (g_main_context_check(context, max_priority, pfds, glib_n_poll_fds)) {
        g_main_context_dispatch(context);
    }
}
static int os_host_main_loop_wait(int64_t timeout)
{
    GMainContext *context = g_main_context_default();
    int ret;

    g_main_context_acquire(context);

    glib_pollfds_fill(&timeout);

    qemu_mutex_unlock_iothread();
    replay_mutex_unlock();

    ret = qemu_poll_ns((GPollFD *)gpollfds->data, gpollfds->len, timeout); //RESOLVES TO: g_poll(fds, nfds, qemu_timeout_ns_to_ms(timeout));

    replay_mutex_lock();
    qemu_mutex_lock_iothread();

    glib_pollfds_poll(); 

    g_main_context_release(context);

    return ret;
}
```

So, as I understand, `g_poll` polls the array of file descriptors with a timeout. What it means? It means it waits for the timeout. If something happens (there's data in the fd to be read for example), I don't know what it does.

Then `glib_pollfds_poll` calls `g_main_context_check` and then `g_main_context_dispatch`.

According to glib's documentation, what `g_main_context_check` does is:

> Passes the results of polling back to the main loop.

What that means?

Then `g_main_context_dispatch`

> dispatches all sources

, which I also don't know what it means.

Entire source can be founde here: https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/14e5526b51910efd62cd31cd95b49baca975c83f/util/main-loop.c